# Theano scan acts strangely after 127 steps

Tags: python, theano

I'm confused about how Theano scan works. I would expect the following function to monotonically increase, but this doesn't happen:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt
i = 500
x, _ = theano.scan(fn=lambda previous_count: previous_count+1, outputs_info=0, n_steps=i)
f = theano.function(inputs=[], outputs=x)
f()
```

The output:

```
array([   1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9,   10,   11,
     12,   13,   14,   15,   16,   17,   18,   19,   20,   21,   22,
     23,   24,   25,   26,   27,   28,   29,   30,   31,   32,   33,
     34,   35,   36,   37,   38,   39,   40,   41,   42,   43,   44,
     45,   46,   47,   48,   49,   50,   51,   52,   53,   54,   55,
     56,   57,   58,   59,   60,   61,   62,   63,   64,   65,   66,
     67,   68,   69,   70,   71,   72,   73,   74,   75,   76,   77,
     78,   79,   80,   81,   82,   83,   84,   85,   86,   87,   88,
     89,   90,   91,   92,   93,   94,   95,   96,   97,   98,   99,
    100,  101,  102,  103,  104,  105,  106,  107,  108,  109,  110,
    111,  112,  113,  114,  115,  116,  117,  118,  119,  120,  121,
    122,  123,  124,  125,  126,  127, -128, -127, -126, -125, -124,
   -123, -122, -121, -120, -119, -118, -117, -116, -115, -114, -113,

...], dtype=int8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm dumb ... the type was set to `int8`!